# Converting (unknown) type to string/char - python

Tags: python, arrays, char

I am writing a little interpreter for BrainFuck.
My problem lies here, I have two lists

```
#This holds ASCII (number) value
mem = []
#This list holds character corresponding to ASCII number.
letMem = []
```

Before checking tokens I have a function that looks at the value of each item in the list mem, and adds their ASCII correspondent to the same position in letMem.

After, if that value needs to be printed, it prints the char value in letMem.

Finally, my problem, nothing prints out, I checked by printing letMem in the loop, it returns:

```
letMem = ['\xtf']
```

What is that? Can I convert it to a string/char?

If so how?

Or am I doing something wrong..?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  A list can never print that as shown.  It is an illegal escape sequence.  for example, `letMem = ['\xtf']` generates an error in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: The `\x` means the following two characters are interpreted as hex digits for the character code. But i can't figure out why there is a `t` in it.

Comment: Not sure of the root issue, you should follow recommendations of @MarkTolonen, anyway, if you just want to print "\xtf" you have to use _raw_ string: `print r'\xtf'`

Comment: @Arount, to print as displayed, it would need to be `print(r"['\xtf']")`, which is unlikely and why actual code needs to be shown.

Comment: yes, just wanted to give a possibly useful keyword "_raw strings_".